# hInterface 'Throwable' not found

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

when querying the database with sql error laravel throws Throwable interface not found instead of the query exception.[image]

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: The error is: `Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Info\DB' not found`

Comment: thanks @AlessandroL. I've uploaded the right screenshot.

Comment: @AlessandroL. the code is simple for example if I did this DB::table('users')->get();  where the users tables doesn't exist in database I get this exception instead Query Exception.

Answer (score 0):

i have a same trouble yestoday with 'laravel new demo', meybe the repository server has error before. i rebuild my laravel project with 'composer create-project laravel/laravel=5.4 demo --prefer-dist' this afternoon, it work! do like this.

Answer (score 0):

In my last project, I got this error too. I used php 5.6.30 version. When i upgrade to 7.0.1 version, everything is fine. http://php.net/manual/en/class.throwable.php

Answer (score 0):

I was using `php5.6` and got this after I did `composer update`.

So I installed the `php7.1` following this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/856793/upgrade-to-the-specific-php-7-1-from-php-7-0-in-ubuntu-16-04)

Then I disabled `php5.6` using

```
sudo a2dismod php5.6
```

and then I ran the following to enable 7.1

```
sudo a2enmod php7.1
```

and finally restarted apache2 using.

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed mine when I did a netstat -tln and found out the mysql is running 0:0:0:0:3306, and on my .env file is set to DB_HOST= 127.0.0.1. I changed it to DB_HOST=localhost and is working fine right now.